# Spring Validation with applyIf attribute in Annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-annotations

I've tried to set **applyIf** attribute on spring annotation with some custom exspression. As exampe I have a form:

```
class MyForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @MinSize(applyIf = "name not equals myValue", value = 1) 
    private List<String> addresses;
    ...
}
```

But when I try to validate form above spring perceives **myValue** from exspression as property. The it tries to find getters setters for it.

Also, I've tried to dig `org.springmodules.validation.valang.parser.ValangParser`, but unfortunatly java docs are not present for this class.

I can't find any examples with this stuff(Only really simple cases like: "**name is not blank**"). Will be good if you suggest some usefull documentation. Or correct my exspression for correct verifying my goals.

Comment: "name NOT EQUALS 'myValue'" ?

Comment: I'm not sure NOT EQUALS works http://www.springbyexample.org/maven/site/sbe-validation/0.92/apidocs/org/springmodules/validation/valang/ValangValidator.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, This "name NOT EQUALS 'myValue'" works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comment under the question, the syntax should be "name NOT EQUALS 'myValue'"

http://www.springbyexample.org/maven/site/sbe-validation/0.92/apidocs/org/springmodules/validation/valang/ValangValidator.html